# How to use index in filter in a "dask-sql" SQL query

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

I create a sample dask dataframe with the timestamp as an index.

```
df = dask.datasets.timeseries()

df.head()
                       id      name         x         y
timestamp                                              
2000-01-01 00:00:00   915   Norbert -0.989381  0.974546
2000-01-01 00:00:01  1026     Zelda  0.919731  0.656581
2000-01-01 00:00:02  1003  Patricia -0.128303 -0.354592
2000-01-01 00:00:03   986     Jerry  0.557732  0.160812
```

Now I want to use dask-sql and a filter on the index in an SQL query. This does not work however:

```py
from dask_sql import Context

c = Context()
c.create_table("mytab", df)

result = c.sql("""
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM mytab
        WHERE "timestamp" > '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
    """)
print(result.compute())
```

The Error Message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/dask_sql/startup_script.py", line 15, in <module>
    result = c.sql("""
  File "/opt/dask_sql/dask_sql/context.py", line 458, in sql
    rel, select_names, _ = self._get_ral(sql)
  File "/opt/dask_sql/dask_sql/context.py", line 892, in _get_ral
    raise ParsingException(sql, str(e.message())) from None
dask_sql.utils.ParsingException: Can not parse the given SQL: From line 4, column 15 to line 4, column 25: Column 'timestamp' not found in any table

The problem is probably somewhere here:

    
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM timeseries
            WHERE "timestamp" > '2000-01-01'
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am using this docker image `nbraun/dask-sql:2022.1.0`.

Is there an efficient way to get all the rows based on an index filter? It is important that this can be done in dask-sql because I need to execute the SQL via the presto endpoint provided by the [dask-sql-server](https://dask-sql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/server.html).

Comment: Could you please share the error traceback as well? It'll help us better diagnose what's happening :)

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the column name "timestamp". If I rename that index to "tsp" and try the corresponding SQL, then I just get a datatype error message `Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and datetime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dask-sql doesn't seem to identify "timestamp" as the index-column-name, so one workaround is to use `reset_index`:

```py
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

from dask_sql import Context


ddf = dask.datasets.timeseries()


c = Context()
c.create_table("mytab", ddf.reset_index())


result = c.sql("""
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM mytab
        WHERE "timestamp" > '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
    """)

print(result.compute())
```

In this specific example, we get `TypeError('Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and datetime')` because pandas/Dask use the `datetime64ns` format. You can convert the "timestamp" column to be in `datetime` format using something like:

```py
import datetime

c.create_table("mytab", ddf.reset_index().assign(timestamp = lambda df: df["timestamp"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), meta=('timestamp', 'object'))))
```

Which is similar to,

```py
ddf_new = ddf.reset_index()

ddf_new["timestamp"] = ddf_new["timestamp"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), meta=('timestamp', 'object'))

c.create_table(ddf_new)
```

I'd also encourage you to open relevant issues on the [dask-sql issue tracker](https://github.com/dask-contrib/dask-sql) to reach the team directly. :)

Comment: For the desired index filter the index just needs to be renamed: `ddf = ddf.reset_index().rename(columns={"timestamp": "tsp"}).set_index("tsp")`
The datatype issue seems to be unrelated to the original problem. I will create an issue in the dask-sql repo.